# JSF mudar informações no XHTML

Tags: java, jsf, front-end

Boa noite.

Tenho uma aplicação em java/jsf estou com uma dificuldade em mostrar informações no XHTML,

Bem eu tenho um `SelectOneMenu` para salvar uma informação no banco:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="PermissaoAcesso"
    value="#{usuarioManageBean.usuario.permissaoAcesso}" required="true"
    label="PermissaoAcesso">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{permissaoView.permissoes}" />
    <f:validateLength minimum="1" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="displayEquipe1" process="@this" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="displayEquipe2" process="@this" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Ele puxa as informações de uma classe chamada `PermissaoView`:

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        permissoes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        permissoes.put("Supervisor", "1");
        permissoes.put("Atendente", "2");
        permissoes.put("Pronta Resposta", "3");
    }
```

Por causa de algumas regras de negocio ele salva no banco os valores 1, 2 e 3

Ok, ele salva no banco, quando eu puxo as informações em um `dataTable` é lógico que ele vai puxar as informações 1, 2 e 3. aqui esta a linha do código que puxa a informação no `datatable` é essa:

```
<p:column headerText="Permissão de Acesso"
        style="text-align: center">
        <h:outputText value="#{listausuario.permissaoAcesso}" />
</p:column>
```

como eu disse, ele mostra as informações que eu salvei, que no caso são 1, 2 e 3, agora minha dificuldade é no `xhtml` mudar esses dados para para os nomes de cada valor exemplo valor 1 no `datatable` mostrar Supervisor, vi em alguns lugares na net que eu posso usar `Enum`, mas não sei bem como ele funciona. Alguem pode me dar uma luz? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor seria usar `enum`.

Do jeito que está, a solução é a seguinte:

**1 - Crie este método na sua classe:**

```
public String permissaoAcessoFormatada(){
   switch (permissaoAcesso) {
     case "1":
     return "Supervisor";
     case "2":
     return "Admin";
     case "3":
     return "Mestre";
     default:
     return null;
   }
}
```

**2 - Use o método no seu `dataTable`:**

```
<p:column headerText="Permissão de Acesso"
        style="text-align: center">
        <h:outputText value="#{listausuario.permissaoAcessoFormatada()}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: Perfeito man, deu certinho, obrigado.